# CSS Horizontal navigation bar with background color

Tags: css

Why does this code produce only a white background:

```
 ul.nav {
   width: 30%;
   border: 1px solid #999;
   margin: 0px auto;
   background-color: #00ff7f;
 }
 ul.nav li {
   display: inline;
   float: left;
   width: 20%;         
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1) Start more basically and give your elements height and width.  At the stage of CSS dev you are probably at, percentages will only confuse you.  Additionally, you should alphabetize all of the css properties you use; it will give you code some zen my friend.

2) Lose the display:inline; reference and replace it with display:block;.  Display inline will only take up the room it needs, nothing more.  In your code, it doesn't need to take up any space because you have only defined the spaces as a percentages.  You could read more here: http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/

Try this code instead:

```
 ul.nav {
   background-color: #00ff7f;       
   border: 1px solid #999;
   height: 20px; /*This is an example*/
   margin: 0px auto;
   width: 400px;        
 }

 ul.nav li {
   background-color: #86182d; /*Example background color*/
   display: block;
   float: left;
   height: 20px; /*This is an example*/
   width: 80px;  /*This is 20% of 400px*/      
 }
```

This will definitely output something tangible you can work back from with percentages as you learn more.

3)  For every question someone answers on here for you, try and answer one yourself.  It will help you learn more than you imagined.  Good luck in coding...

Answer (score 1):

The UL collapses due to the inner floated elements (the li's). Clear the UL with an overflow: hidden on the ul.nav.

```
ul.nav
{
   width: 30%;
   border: 1px solid #999;
   margin: 0px auto;
   background-color: #00ff7f;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: or `overflow: auto`. Any value for overflow will do

Answer (score 0):

Since all of the children of ul.nav are floated, the ul.nav has to content to give it height. Since its height is zero, no background colour renders. You can confirm the ul's size using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: Thanks! How can I fix it so that it's height is for example text height inside li-element +5 px?

Answer (score 0):

just delete the `float` from  `ul.nav li` and change the `display:inline` to `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

because your li is displayed inline and floating, which means that the containing ul does net get height from its children. Either give the ul a height or have a containing element around the ul and a clear: both after the ul and give that a background color

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked many times and in many ways: "Why isn't the container encapsulating my floated items?". It's because css is not a programming language, it is a styling language. CSS reacts fluidly and implicitly and many programmers expect to need to give explicit instructions.

I highly recommend you read more about floating in css. quirksmode has a good [page about it](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html). Additionally you should read the [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats) to get a deeper understanding on the subject.

Comment: yes, it's because with floating images in text you don't want every paragraph clearing the images. That would possibly mess up the  whitespace in between paragraphs.